# I am not getting download url in microsoft graph api one drive endpoints

Tags: python-2.7, microsoft-graph-api, rest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

here the link for downloading drive item and I am doing it but in content I am not getting location instead of receiving content of item

```
resopnse = obj_MicrosoftOneDrive.downloadlinkUsingId(userId, rootItemID,
                                                     userPrincipalName)
if resopnse != None:
    print  resopnse
    # print "aaafffc", resopnse.content
else:
    print response
```

I am able to get the download link in get item using ID but not able to do it using this endpoints any suggestions? Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: the location is returned in the response header.

Comment: Nope there is no location is returned in headers

Comment: ok, I think whatever library that you are using to send the request understands the 302 status code and it is automatically redirecting to the Location url in header and downloading the content for you. Easiest way to figure this out is is by setting up wireshark. You should see two outgoing requests